# Why isn't Javascript working in Google's example code for the new style of Chrome extension options pages?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, html-select

I'm trying to follow the example code for the newer style of making [options pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2). I've added an options.html and options.js file with the exact content that they list on that page. I've also added the "options_ui" section to my manifest.json (and removed the trailing comma after '"chrome_style": true').

When I do this I am able to open the options window for the extension but the saving and loading functionality do not work. I've tried adding in some console logs and alerts and these don't seem to be executing either. I can't find any errors or warnings anywhere but I just can't figure out how to get the JavaScript to execute. Does anybody know what I need to do differently?

Edit: I'm adding the source files here to make it easier for people to scan through them and for posterity.

*manifest.json*

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "My extension",
  "description": "test extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "options_ui": {
    // Required.
    "page": "options.html",
    // Recommended.
    "chrome_style": true
    // Not recommended; only provided for backwards compatibility,
    // and will be unsupported in a future version of Chrome (TBD).
    //"open_in_tab": true
  }
}
```

*options.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Test Extension Options</title>
  <style>
    body: { padding: 10px; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  Favorite color:
  <select id="color">
   <option value="red">red</option>
   <option value="green">green</option>
   <option value="blue">blue</option>
   <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
  </select>

  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="like">
    I like colors.
  </label>

  <div id="status"></div>
  <button id="save">Save</button>

  <script src="options.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*options.js*

```
// Saves options to chrome.storage.sync.
function save_options() {
  var color = document.getElementById('color').value;
  var likesColor = document.getElementById('like').checked;
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    favoriteColor: color,
    likesColor: likesColor
  }, function() {
    // Update status to let user know options were saved.
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.textContent = 'Options saved.';
    setTimeout(function() {
      status.textContent = '';
    }, 750);
  });
}

// Restores select box and checkbox state using the preferences
// stored in chrome.storage.
function restore_options() {
  // Use default value color = 'red' and likesColor = true.
  chrome.storage.sync.get({
    favoriteColor: 'red',
    likesColor: true
  }, function(items) {
    document.getElementById('color').value = items.favoriteColor;
    document.getElementById('like').checked = items.likesColor;
  });
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click',
    save_options);
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include relevant parts of your code. As is, no one can guess what might be wrong, and the link to Chrome's example code may break in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I added the contents of each file to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) API, you have to [declare](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) the `storage` permission in the manifest file.

If you right-clicked on your options page, selected "Inspect element" (to open the devtools), and switched to the Console tab, then you would have received the "Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined" error.